# My template that iterates through elements in my database does not work?

Tags: debugging, meteor

The relevant template portions is as follows:

```
<template name="list_of_links">
   <ul id="item-list">
        {{#each my_playlist}}
            {{> link_item}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="link_item">
<li class="link">
    <div class="destroy"></div>
    <div class="link-title">{{youtube_link}}</div>
</li>
</template>
```

And the relevant Javascript in the client is:

```
  //Songs from session
    Template.list_of_links.my_playlist = function () {
      return Links.find({sess: Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId}, {sort: {score: -1}});
    };
```

However, whenever I insert things through a text input into the Links collection, I do not see anything being updated on the page.

I am able to see the values in the db when I print to log manually however, and calling: Template.list_of_links.my_playlist() does give me the desired output.

Also, youtube_link is a field within the Links collection, I am uncertain about the way I am using it in the link_item template.

Comment: Can you add an example of a document in the Links collection?

Comment: @BenjaminRH Like so? I input two fields - "sess" and "youtube_link": http://i.imgur.com/0zv1GJR.png

Comment: Can you perhaps share the results of the following: In the browser console, run `Links.find({sess: Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId}).count()` and then add a new document like you said you tried, and then run that again, and post the two numbers you got?

Comment: @BenjaminRH Sure thing: http://i.imgur.com/LNAAGYR.png

Comment: Unless you're getting any errors in the console you haven't mentioned, and assuming you've removed the youtube_link helper, I don't see what could be causing this problem. Maybe you just need to kill the meteor app and run it again?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that @BenjaminRH. Would seeing more of the template help? In any case here it is: http://ideone.com/XGlcgW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you just get rid of the bit below? It's entirely unnecessary.

```
Template.link_item.youtube_link = function () {
    return this.youtube_link;
};
```

The reason that doesn't work is because `this` in a Template helper isn't the actual bit of data. From the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_inst):

> Template instance objects are found as the value of this in the created, rendered, and destroyed template callbacks and as an argument to event handlers.

Comment: I actually added that based on the advice of the other answer. I do not see the page update when I take it out either. 

Here is the entire Javascript file for reference, I have omitted the portion you've mentioned.  ideone.com/gof1C8

Comment: Oh, haha, I didn't notice that. Lemme take a look around again.

Answer (score 0):

`{{youtube_link}}` in the `link_item` template won't return anything cause it's the `list_of_links` template that gets passed the values from the database. So I guess your DOM acutally updates, it's just that it's an empty that gets appended, like this:

```
<li class="link">
    <div class="destroy"></div>
    <div class="link-title"></div>
</li>
```

So you need to add a `youtube_link`-helper to the `link_item` template and return the value you want from there.

(I don't remember from the top of my mind, but I think you can just do this):

```
Template.link_item.youtube_link = function () {
  return this.youtube_link;
};
```

Comment: Hello, I made that change, and did not see anything different. The Javascript console shows that there are no empty links being updated, it remains like this as I add links onto the database: http://i.imgur.com/WC14xrx.png

Comment: What could be other sources of the problem?